# C# Getting wrong decimal value from EF6 Code-First DB with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, decimal

We have a code-first database in our project, with a decimal in one of our models.
We set the decimal precision to (6, 2), which we checked in our mysql database's structure.
The collation of the db is `utf8_unicode_ci`.

We saved a value of `4.00` to the database from a view, which was correct. However, now that we try to get the value back from the db, in stead of getting `4.00` or `4.00m`, we get `400M`. The comma is just *gone*.

All help appreciated.

(But please, don't suggest dividing by 100. That's ugly fixing and you know it.)

**EDIT**
Model:

```
public class RSU
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual RSUSlot SlotRef { get; set; }
    public decimal? Length { get; set; }
}
```

INSERT code:

```
using(dbCOntext db = new dbCOntext())
{
    db.Add(new RSU{ Length = 4.00m });
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

GET:

```
public static CabinetConfig GetCabinet(M4CDbContext db, int id)
{
    return db.CabinetConfig
        .Include(m => m.RSURef)
        .Where(m => m.Id == id)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Cannot replicate this problem. Can show us your problem through an **sql fiddle**?

Comment: Also, please provide the code of the `INSERT` and the `SELECT` of the `decimal`.

Comment: Afraid I can't reproduce in a fiddle. If we run `select * from rsu` in our local database we get a list with values `4.00`.
It's a MVC project with EF6

Comment: Edited to show model, insert and get

Comment: Where did you set the Decimal Precision in Code? And which kind of EF your are using?

Comment: In the DbCOntext we set `modelBuilder.Entity<RSU>().Property(x => x.Length).HasPrecision(6, 2);`. We're using EF6 (MySql)

Comment: Are you sure you provide correct `Id` at filter `.Where(m => m.Id == id)`?

Comment: yes, 100% sure. We get the right fields, just the wrong value for the decimal.

Comment: What does this syntax mean?  `4.00m` ?  It is not a valid literal in any language I know.

Comment: What is EF6?  Could it be messing things up?

Comment: `EF6` = `Entity Framework 6`. and `4.00m` is specific for decimals. Don't know if it's messing things up. We've just tested another model and can retrieve the decimal values just fine. It's a mystery as to why this specific one won't work.

Answer (score 0):

<del>I'm not sure why this isn't working with MySQL but an idea would be:</del>

Use the `Fluent API` approach and create `EntityTypeConfiguration` for your class:

```
public class RSUConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<RSU>
{
    public RSUConfiguration()
    {
        Property(x => x.Length)
            .HasPrecision(6, 2);
    }
}
```

And add it to your `modelBuilder`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<RSU>().Property(x => x.Length).HasPrecision(6, 2);    
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RSUConfiguration());

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: We used your method, but nothing changed. We still have `4.00` in the database, and see `400M` returned to our model.

Comment: Have you recreated the database after changing to this approach?

Comment: Yes. We've executed a migration.

Comment: Which kind of `MySqlConnector` do you use? Is the Database encoding set in the `Connection String`?

Comment: In our web.config we have `<add name="M4C" connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;port=3306;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=M4C" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />`. We don't set database encoding anywhere

Comment: Add `CharSet=utf8;` to the connection string. Could be changing the resultset.

Comment: Doesn't change anything either. We have found another model in the meanwhile, where getting the decimal value does work. We're comparing code from there but find no differences so far.

Comment: I'm working on a project where I faced the same situation and I'm thinking that this is a bug because it only happens when you use Include, if you query using the context directly it will work.